# Type literal line feed in SQL string

Tags: sql, sql-server, phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.1

I'm editing SQL in a *.sql file for SQL Server. When I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to split a SQL string in two lines:

```
INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ('This is a line');
                      -- Cursor here: |
```

... PhpStorm will always close the string and insert a concatenation operator:

```
INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ('This is' +
                              ' a line');
```

Is there a keyboard-shortcut to just insert a line feed?

```
INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ('This is
   a line');
```

Comment: What context is that? Is that pure SQL (e.g. some `.sql` file or SQL Console) .. or some language injection fragment (e.g. string in PHP/JavaScript etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | General | Smart Keys`
3. Disable `SQL --> Insert string concatenation on Enter` option

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I guess there's no way to keep the feature yet opt-out in individual cases (just like *Paste simple* allows to opt-out from auto-format on paste).

Comment: I've tried all possible combos I could think of -- none of them have split the line by just inserting the line feed. With this new option disabled thought you may still use `Alt+Enter` to split the line with concatenation.

Comment: This is the ticket that have introduced such option (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-2938) ... as such functionality was simply introduced without alternatives. You may create another ticket asking to possibly introduce the ability to enter the line feed even with that option enabled.